# EMR Presto LDAPS: authenticator not loaded

Tags: presto, openldap

LDAPS is correctly set up using [docker-openldap](https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap).

- Certificates correctly generated and deployed (also tried self generated certificates)
- `ldapwhoami` and `ldapsearch` both works
- Presto complains `authenticator not loaded`, with `DEBUG` level logging it says "simple bind failed: outbound connection failed"

Answer (score 0):

It turns out by default `osixia/openldap` container will run with TLS client certificate verification on (`demand`). This requires a local certificate and a private key, i.e. the ldap server will try to validate client owns a valid certificate.

`ldapwhoami` works because the client certificate was imported to local machine, but on Presto node only a root certificate was imported during initialization.

The error message was not clear, showing `UncheckedException`, `authenticator not loaded`, `simple bind failed`, etc.

The solution is to disable client certificate verification. When launching the docker, add `--env LDAP_TLS_VERIFY_CLIENT=try` or `never`.

Importing the private key to default Java keystore *might* also work if client verification is desired.